# Flutter remove all routes using auto_route

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes

In case of error, I want to redirect my users to the same flow again (in order to reset the flow state).

I'm using the [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#navigating-between-screens) package for navigation, and I can see that `router.replace` and `router.replaceAll` do not replace (remove and insert from the stack) the same routes again (it just updates them).

From the official documentation:

```
// removes last entry in stack and pushs provided route            
// if last entry == provided route page will just be updated
router.replace(const BooksListRoute())

// This's like providing a completely new stack as it rebuilds the stack          
// with the list of passed routes          
// entires might just update if already exist          
router.replaceAll([          
   LoginRoute()          
]);
```

**How can I "hard reset" replace a route, or stack of routes, using `auto_route` package?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solved.

In order to "hard reset" the same page using [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) package, Use `pushAndPopUntil` function, with a `predicate` set to always `false`.

That way, all pages will be removed, and the provided stack will be inserted instead (in other words, a full replacement, even for the same page).

Then your page will reinitiate, and all state values will be reset (same as redirecting to a new page).

```
await _router.pushAndPopUntil(
    const LoginRoute(),
    predicate: (_) => false,
)
```

Comment: its not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add this package :

```
dependencies:
  flutter_phoenix: ^1.1.0
```

Example:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    Phoenix(
      child: App(),
    ),
  );
}
```

---

```
Phoenix.rebirth(context);
```

Phoenix restarts your application at the application level, rebuilding your application widget tree from scratch, losing any previous state.

Phoenix does not fully restart your application process at the OS level.

Comment: This solution resets the hole app, while I'm looking to reset the same page again